# SwipeGestureRecognizer not working properly for left, up, and down in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement swipeGestureRecognizer for all four directions in a swift app, on a bunch of dynamically generated UIViews.  So basically, I want each of these views to respond to swipes in all four directions.  Here is my code

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    //create a view to represent the main box
    let mainBox = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 40 ))
        mainBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        mainBox.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        mainBox.layer.borderWidth=1
        self.view.addSubview(mainBox) //Add the newly created view to the main view(self)





    //Create some UIViews on the fly

    for var i=0; i<8; ++i{
        //Add an image view
        let tile = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(i)*CGFloat(40),0,40,40 )) //Create a new view
        //Style the imageview
        tile.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
        tile.layer.cornerRadius=2
        tile.layer.borderWidth=1


        tile.userInteractionEnabled = true

        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("tileRightSwiped:"))
        swipeRight.direction = .Right
        tile.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tileLeftSwiped"))
        swipeLeft.direction = .Left
        tile.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)


        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tileDownSwiped"))
        swipeDown.direction = .Down
        tile.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)


        let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tileUpSwiped"))
        swipeUp.direction = .Up
        tile.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)











        mainBox.addSubview(tile) //Add the newly created view to mainBox


    }




}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





//swipe gestures
func tileRightSwiped(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("right swiped")
}

func tileLeftSwiped(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("left swiped ")
}

func tileDownSwiped(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("down swiped ")
}

func tileUpSwiped(gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    print("Up swiped ")
}




}
```

Right swipe works just fine but I can't understand why for the other 3 directions, the app aborts unexpectedly and I get an error like this
"[myApp.ViewController tileDownSwiped]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd230dbf5d0"  Am I incorrectly using the swipegesture recognizer or is something wrong somewhere else in my code?
I'm at a total loss.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Wain and Duncan.  I was missing the semicolon and that's what was causing the problem.  Works fine now. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectors you have added to the gestures are wrong because you have missed the colons of the end. This is the reason for the crash you see.

You may also need to add a delegate to the gesture recognisers and implement [`shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:) so they will all work at the same time.

Comment: Expanding on Wain's answer a little, a selector uses colons to indicate how many parameters the method has. If it has no colons, it specifies a method with no parameters. If your selector is `Selector("method:")`, then `method()` has 1 parameter. If the selector is `Selector("method::")` then `method()` has 2 parameters. Your methods all have 1 parameter, so you need colons in the selector strings for all of them.